# A paper of Jean Bourgain accessible to an undergraduate?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request

The title is pretty much the question : the acclaimed mathematician Jean Bourgain recently passed away, there is a tribute on the blog of Terry Tao.

Apparently, most of his papers are deep and technical, but :

> what are some of his  most accessible ones, say in the broad area of real analysis/functional analysis (after following an advanced course like [Brezis' book](https://www.springer.com/la/book/9780387709130)) ?
>
> *[edit:]* or indeed in any other area, if it is more suitable.

Many thanks!